# Live Reload is not possible without body or head tag

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Noobs</h1>
    <p>KodySimpson Tutorial</p>

    <script src="KodySimpson/hello.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of my screen so you can see what I am seeing:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbZFd.png)

I am very new to js, and I have tried searching for answers to this but I cannot see a solution for my issue. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to reload the page using javascript?

Comment: So you don’t have an actual programming question here, but rather a problem with a feature of a specific IDE? Then I would suggest that you go consult the documentation for that first of all.

Comment: Try to replace `KodySimpson/hello.js` with `hello.js` in script's src

Answer (score -1):

Edit :

Here is the solution for Visual Code Live Reload `ng-controller="..."` :

https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/22

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    </body>
</html>
```

Previous response :

The javascript and the html files are in the same folder.

Use :

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="./hello.js"></script>
```

Comment: That does not work. According to what I do know, I have to consider the folder that it's in being KodySimpson but either way it's still giving me that error and will not update life.

Comment: What is the real url of the file : http://127.0.0.1:5500/KodySimpson/KodySimpson/hello.js or http://127.0.0.1:5500/KodySimpson/hello.js ? What is hello.js ? Provide hello.js code, it will be more clear for all I think.

Comment: Isuue on Visual Code : https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/22

Answer (score -1):

remove the title "Document" from your code and the live reload will work just fine. Worked for me. it seems to create a conflict between your  and the IP address the extension wants to use.  the reason why ? i do not know. worked for me.  i got the error ,deleted the "tittle" and got my live session working but pop up still shows though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I am on windows machine, same problem happened to me when I used command line to create the file. I deleted the file and used GUI to create another file, the problem is gone.